# Print Dialog Pdf print using iText

Tags: java, pdf, jsf, itext

I am using **iText** to create a PDF file and print it using the following code:

```
Document iText_xls_2_pdf = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, response.getOutputStream());
iText_xls_2_pdf.open();

PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
writer.setOpenAction(action);
iText_xls_2_pdf.close();
```

It works fine the first time i.e it opens the print dialog as expected.
Once the user closes the print dialog and invokes same code again it does not do anything.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Note:** I am doing this operation in `doGet` method of the *servlet*.

Comment: I'm not sure why your question received a down-vote. You are giving a description of a problem in a way that any developer can understand it. Maybe there is no solution to your problem (in case the problem is caused by the viewer on the client-side), but (1.) there are some things you can try anyway (see my answer), and (2.) if there is no solution to your problem, people should say so instead of casting a down-vote. I up-voted to get you back on a neutral score.

Answer (score 1):

First this: the code you are using to add an open action is correct. Any PDF viewer who opens the PDF document you are creating should trigger the print dialog to appear.

You know that your iText code is right because it works the first time the PDF is opened. In your case, this happens in a browser. It is unclear which PDF viewer is used: pdf.js in Firefox? Chrome's PDF viewer? Preview on Apple? Adobe Reader?

> **Note:** you shouldn't assume that every PDF viewer implements the complete PDF specification. Some viewers ignore the open action, others don't even know what the PrintDialog action is about.

You write: *Once the user closes the print dialog and invokes same code again it does not do anything.*

This is a strange way to put things. There is no code to trigger by the user. The action is triggered by the open action, not by clicking some button or by selecting some menu option. It would help if you'd explain what you mean when you say "invokes same code again."

For now, let's assume that "invoking the same code again" is the equivalent of refreshing/reloading the page. In that case, it's possible that the PDF is never re-opened because it hasn't expired yet. Maybe the PDF viewer in your browser says: *"Hey, the document I am showing now, is the same document that I have in my cache. I don't need to reopen it."* And if the document is never reopened, there is no reason to trigger the open action once more.

When you serve the PDF to the browser, which headers are you setting?

Can you try adding these lines at the appropriate place in your `doGet()` method:

```
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
    "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
```

Note that `baos` is a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. It is wrong to do this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, response.getOutputStream());
```

You should do it like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, baos);
// do a lot of other stuff
```

At the very last (especially *after* setting the headers), you write the content to the `OutputStream` of the `response` object:

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

See the official FAQ: [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side)

If all of this doesn't help, your problem is caused by something on the client-side. In that case, there is no answer to your question. We can only tell you that you're not doing anything wrong. This is the correct way to add an open action:

```
PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
writer.setOpenAction(action);
```

If this doesn't work, the only answer you can get on Stack Overflow will be: "You're code is correct" (provided that you follow the advice on the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and the HTTP headers).